# How to setup Kubuntu to hibernate when I press the power button on my laptop?

Tags: shutdown, kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu and expected something similar to Windows's Power Management applet in the Control Panel. I want my laptop to Hibernate when I press the power button, instead of doing it manually from the menu. Preferably using some GUI management tool, not the console.

Comment: Really? No one? It's been two weeks, people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KMenu -> System Settings -> Advanced -> Power Management -> Edit Profiles has all the adjustments, and includes power button suspend to disk.

Comment: does not work on mine ( A am using version 12 )