# Making Ubuntu Sleep When Laptop Lid Closes

Tags: linux, laptop, power-management, kde, kubuntu

I am a brand new user of Kubuntu 10.0.4. So far, one of the major things I miss is the ability to have my system sleep when I close the lid of my laptop. Any tips on how to enable this behavior?

Note: as I said, I'm brand new to linux, so the simpler you can explain things, the better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/100305/how-to-setup-kubuntu-to-hibernate-when-i-press-the-power-button-on-my-laptop/119406#119406)

KMenu -> System Settings -> Advanced -> Power Management -> Edit Profiles has all the adjustments, and includes options for power button suspend to disk, reacting to laptop lid closing, etc.

Comment: You should mark this as an accepted answer, so that everybody can see in the overview that you have an answer.

Comment: @Yaba: Thanks for the reminder. At the time that I answered, I wasn't able to accept my own answer. Done now.

Answer (score 1):

A Nice tutorial from http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_acpid might help.

Checkout the sub section -> `Example: go to sleep on lid close`

Comment: The KDE/Kubuntu specificity of the answer I found fits more with what I'm looking for, but I'm sure that wiki will come in handy and would have worked if there weren't a built in solution.